# edited text value are clear when move to next value and come back at current activity

Tags: android

I have an activity which have on listview and edit texts.
Here when i have to fetch data from listview there is an click event mehod on textview where fetched data from listview is stored.
But Problem is that
edit text entered data cleared when i choose data from listview..
So
what should i do
if I want my edit text data as it is after coming back from selecting listview data from another activity.

I tried finish() at click event but its not working.data are being cleared.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Store those data in your array whenever there is data change. You can use below logic, which I generally use in my project

```
private boolean programmaticalTextChange = false;

private KeyEvent UnknownKey = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_UNKNOWN);

    public class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher
    {
        private EditText editText;

        public MyTextWatcher(EditText editText)
        {
            this.editText = editText;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            if (!programmaticalTextChange)
                editText.dispatchKeyEvent(UnknownKey);
        }
    }


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       //...
       myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                updateItem(item, v, rowView);
                return false;
            }
        });
        myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(myEditText));

}

protected void updateItem(MyClass item, View v) {
        try {
            item.Name = ((EditText) v).getText()
                    .toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many options. You can use shared preferences. When you are in that activity, you create a shared preference object by doing

```
     SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
```

You can store your text from edit text view by doing this

```
    editor.putString("MyPreference", edittext.getText());
```

From your old activity when you return to it you can do

```
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
   String myEditText = preferences.getString("MyPreference") ;
```

Hope it helps.